# SQLCMD not recogized despite install of SQL Server Native Client for SQL2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, tcp, sql-server

This little question is part of a much larger issue I am trying to resolve:

Does SQLCMD require a separate install or is it included with the Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Native Client (which I just installed on my webserver).

Maybe this is just an incorrect path issue. Here is what I tried:

```
C:\>sqlcmd -S tcp:devmojito\mssqlserver2008,1433
   'sqlcmd' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
    operable program or batch file.
C:\>
```

This same syntax works when executed from the c drive on my SQL Server machine.

EDITED:

Path is as follows:

C:>echo %PATH%
C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\client_1\bin;C:\Program Files\Support Tools\;C:\FileNET\Fnsw\Client\Shobj;
C:\PROGRA~1\FileNET\Capture\Programs;C:\FileNET\Shared;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\Sy
stem32\Wbem;C:\Program Files\Dell\SysMgt\oma\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0

I just installed SQL Server 2008 Native Client (SNAC?) yesterday (verified by seeing entry in Control Panel -> Add Remove Program list). Yet at this location:

C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100

I see only 2 subfolders:
    KeyFile
    License Terms

..no Tools and no Binn

I repeated the install of the SNAC and still nothing there.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the SQL Server 2008 Command Line Utiltiies, you can also install the SQL Server client components. This will install SSMS and BIDS, too, though.

As far as the SQL Native Client, consider it similar to the driver which permits a connection to a SQL Server using the most recent options for that version. You'll still need client tools, and that's not included with just the SQL Native Client install.